# what is the difference between mamp and xamp and port numbers?

Tags: xampp, localhost, mamp, server-side, port-number

I know what xampp and mamp stand for I am looking for a simple definition for both and port number?
From what I know port number is just a way that to service can talk but in this sense what are the different ports mamp and xampp? how can I find available ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAMPP and MAMP are more or less similar servers, when you compare mamp with xampp, mamp provides additional service (python) where xampp server doesn't have python support.
There is nothing to worry about port numbers on mamp and xampp. On both servers Apache runs on `port 80`, MySQL runs on `port 3306`. you can have custom port numbers by editing `conf` files